Error when following installation instructions
I am trying to install OpenFOAM on Ubuntu by following the directives on this website and I am at the third step. After the source $HOME/.bashrc command gives error:

/home/<user_name>/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 323: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found.

After the printed error, the echo $WM_PROJECT_DIR gives the expected output /home/<user_name>/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-dev, but echo $ParaView_VERSION prints nothing. If it helps, when starting a terminal I am already in conda base environment.

Is there any reason why you want a conda environment in order to install OF?

It is the base conda environment. It activates automatically when opening a terminal.
